# rsync duplicate tree using hard links

Tags: rsync, hardlink

I would like to duplicate a folder structure containing many directories and files using hard links for all the files instead of making new copies of the files. I thought I could do this with `rsync`, but the `-H` option that I thought did this only preserves existing hard links.

The folder trees I want to do this with are in the same parent directory on the same volume.

Then I thought `--link-dest` might do it:

`rsync -avh --stats --link-dest=Fold1/ Fold1 Fold2/`

But that just copies the files in `Fold1` to `Fold2`

Comment: `cp -al` https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/202431

Comment: That works, thank you, SUPPOSEDLY what I tried in rsync should work https://superuser.com/questions/1360525/can-i-hard-link-files-with-rsync-instead-of-copying-them

Comment: The problem you're having with `--link-dest` is because you're specifying a relative directory, and then it is relative to the destination directory. You should have specified `--link-dest=../Fold1`. I'm also wondering if you should have a trailing slash on your source `Fold1`; if not, the link-dest target should probably be  simply `..`.

Comment: @wurtel I think I tried all those variations, but cp -al works great  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯